# Thread a list of replacement rules into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I think I am missing something simple, so I apologize in advance...

I have two lists

{-1 - $\epsilon$ + 1/2 $\epsilon^2$ x''[0], 1 - $\epsilon$ + 1/2 $\epsilon^2$ x''[0]}

and

{x''[0]-> -1, x''[0]->1}

I simply want to replace `x''[0]` in the first item of the first list with the rule in the first item of the second list, and so on. I have tried using `Thread[]` but I must have the wrong syntax.

I am using this in a class demo, so if it is possible to do this in the least Mathematica way possible (please don't throw things), that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use[`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
list = {-1 - ϵ + 1/2 ϵ^2 x''[0],  1 - ϵ + 1/2 ϵ^ 2 x''[0]};
rules = {x''[0] -> -1, x''[0] -> 1};

MapThread[ReplaceAll,  {list, rules}]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

You can also use [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) as follows:

```
Inner[ReplaceAll, list, rules, List]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

***How to do it with `Thread`***:

If you use `Thread` you need to wrap `ReplaceAll[...]` with [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to prevent `ReplaceAll` being evaluated before `Thread` gets to do its job:

```
Thread[Unevaluated[ReplaceAll[list, rules]]]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

Another way to use `Thread`:

```
ReplaceAll @@@ Thread[{list, rules}]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

***Least Mathematica way:***

My candidate for doing this in the least Mathematicaesq way *in* Mathematica is:

```
For[results = {}; i = 1, i <= 2, i++, AppendTo[results, list[[i]] /. rules[[i]]]]
results
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

***Halloween specials:***

```
☺ = # /. #2 & @@@ ({##}\[Transpose]) &;
☺[list, rules]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

```
☺☺ = {# /. #3, #2 /. #4} & @@ (## & @@@ {##}) &;
☺☺[list, rules]
```

> {-1 - ϵ - ϵ^2/2, 1 - ϵ + ϵ^2/2}

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you! The "Halloween special" gave me a good laugh!

Answer (score 4):

"The least Mathematica way possible"? Something like this?

```
lst = {-1 - ϵ + 1/2 ϵ2 x''[0], 1 - ϵ + 1/2 ϵ2 x''[0]};

rules = {x''[0] -> -1, x''[0] -> 1};

Table[ lst[[i]] /. rules[[i]], {i, Length@rules}]
```